# How to auto-enabled Kong authentication plugin for new APIs?

Tags: authentication, nginx, plugins, kong

We are using Kong in our custom-services deployment system and we developed a new authentication plugin for Kong to suit our specific need.

All of this works well and we tested it doing this:

1. Register a new API (service)
2. Make a POST request to enabled the authentication plugin on the new API

While this works, it opens a window of opportunity for hackers to perform unauthenticated requests between 1. and 2. This is not acceptable obviously but I could not find a way to auto-enable the authentication proxy **automatically**.

Is there a way in Kong to either:

- Auto-enable a given set of plugins for all new APIs.
- Specify the list of plugins to enable when registering a new API.

Comment: have you tried activating your plugin globally and registering the new API (service) after the plugin activation? or your custom auth plugin requires an activation at service level?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to automatically apply a plugin policy to an API at insertion time. There is another issue that could also help (but currently not implemented): https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/1279

Which would allow you to:

1. Add API, but `enabled=false` and no requests can be proxied to it.
2. Add plugins
3. Enable the API with `enabled=true`.

As of today, the only way would be:

1. Add an API with a fake `upstream_url` that goes nowhere.
2. Add plugins.
3. Update the API with a `PATCH` request to now point it to a correct `upstream_url`.